# Magento 2: How to get user agent and remote ip?

Tags: magento2

In magento 1 it

```
$user_agent = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent();
$remote_ip = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
```

Are there any similar features in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this below code :

```
protected $httpHeader;
protected $remoteIp;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remoteIp
)
{
    $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
    $this->remoteIp = $remoteIp;
}
public function execute(){
    $userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();
    $remote_ip = $this->remoteIp->getRemoteAddress();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class DemoClass extends Action {
 private $remoteAddress;

 public function __construct(
     Context $context,
     RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
 ) {
    $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    echo "Visitor's IP = ".$ip;
}
```

}